# Add a role to an existing member?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-cluster

I was looking on the Akka source code. There is a way to get a member's roles (`.getRoles`), but is there a way to add a new role to existing member? I would like to add it dynamically using code and not via configuration.

Comment: @Jawa the concepts of membership and roles refers **specifically to akka-cluster**. Why did [you dropped it out of tag list](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/24432758/revisions)?

Comment: The question was redundantly double-tagged as both Akka and Akka-cluster but it mentioned cluster nowhere in the question. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 2):

No, roles are immutable and cannot be changed after an ActorSystem has been started.

You can change the role programmatically *before* creating the ActorSystem by loading your config file and then overriding the roles value before passing the config object to `ActorSystem.apply` when you initially bootstrap a node.